# Do I have to manage Database concurrency in django?

Tags: django, concurrency

I came across this article
https://medium.com/@hakibenita/how-to-manage-concurrency-in-django-models-b240fed4ee2
Which describes how a request can change a record that another request is currently working with.
Now this article is from 2017 and I haven't found anything about django cobcurrency since.
Also manage.py is single threaded.
Does this mean the issue is now managed by django internally or do I have to manage concurrency manually still when I deploy it with apache?

Comment: manage.py is not single threaded. But no, the issue is not managed by Django.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Requests are usually handled by multiple workers which are in fact different processes. This means that you will be handling simultaneous requests accessing the database so yes, you have to watch for race conditions and the framework will not do that for you.